# Set Proxy credentials in Visual Studio Community when license is expired

Tags: proxy, license, visual-studio-2015

I have an issue setting the proxy for Visual Studio Community. My trial period license has ended, and I am unable to set the credentials for the proxy server my company uses.

I have created the visual studio account using my existing microsoft account, (this is VS community, so free).

I have also gone to the devenv.exe.config and opened it up in notepad to edit the

```
<system.net>
```

block with the proxy credentials. I have added the settings:

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy enabled="true">  
    <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="USERNAME:PASSWORD@http://PROXY IP:PORT"/>  
</defaultProxy>
....
```

and there are no mistakes in the settings I provided.

When I attempt sign in, or open "MyFirstProject" through the website I get the error: proxy authentication required.

Is there a way I can set this information through VS, with the expired license?

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same issue myself, but it looks like your proxy settings are mixed up compared to what works in VS2015 on my machine.

Instead of this format:

```
<proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="USERNAME:PASSWORD@http://PROXY IP:PORT"/>
```

Try using this format:

```
<proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@PROXY IP:PORT"/>
```